# XSLT - placed self node text() to attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a a sample xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <para>AAAAA BBB<s/>CCC DDD<l/>EEEE<t/>FFFFF <style>GGGG</style>HHHHHH</para>
</doc>
```

using XSLT I have to transform this to same node tree but add a name attribute to `<para>` node named `'name'` and it's value should be content text of the `<para>` element.

So the output should be look like,

```
<doc>
    <p name="AAAAA BBB CCC DDD EEEE FFFFF GGGG HHHHHH">AAAAA BBB<s/>CCC DDD<l/>EEEE<t/>FFFFF <style>GGGG</style>HHHHHH</p>
</doc>
```

As you can see in the output, all the text nodes should be copied to the name attribute value a and all inline elements (`<s/>,<t/>,<l/>,<style>`) has to be removed. and all `<s/>`, `<t/>`, `<l/>` has to be replaced with space.

I've written following xslt for this,

```
<xsl:template match="p">
        <p name="{abc:process-attr-text(child::node())}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="abc:process-attr-text">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="$node/text()"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

it gives following output,

```
<doc>
    <p name="GGGG">AAAAA BBB<s/>CCC DDD<l/>EEEE<t/>FFFFF <style>GGGG</style> HHHHHH</p>
</doc>
```

how can I modify my function to get the correct result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is slightly awkward, the obvious answer of just using `<p name="{.}">` won't work because it would simply concatenate all the descendant text nodes, giving `AAAAA BBBCCC DDDEEEEFFFFF GGGGHHHHHH`

If you want to ensure there are spaces wherever there is an XML tag between adjacent text nodes then you need to be a bit more creative. Try

```
<p name="{normalize-space(string-join(descendant::text(), ' '))}">
```

This joins all the text nodes with an extra space between them, then the normalize will squash two adjacent spaces down to one.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <p name="{.}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```